# Bi-Directional MOSFET level converter problem

Tags: avr, level-shifting, reset

I am using standard schematic of level shifter.[image]

It is used to communicate with avr and sometimes reset it. Everything works fine except for reset line. After the first pulling down I am not able to make it high again.

Screen from LA:
[image: Reset line noise]

Closer look:
[image: Closer look]

I have tested it on three different boards. I have checked everything. Nonetheless reset line is still going bananas.

For me it looks like the transistor is closing and opening quite fast. Why I can not imagine. The only difference between reset and other lines is that it has one more pull up(the first one is on the shifter) through 10k to 5v.

What is going on here?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Have revealed that disconnecting arduino/avr from the device results in normal reset line operation. I am trying to load file into avr memory if it makes it clearer.

**SCHEMATIC**

Connected avr is arduino uno/mega. Here it is its [shematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf). You should be interested in ICSP connector. 
For the controlling device I use [cc3200-launchlx board](http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/swrc289) from TI. It connects to arduino over ISP connector.

For cc3200 I have this simple shield:

[image: scheme1]
[image: scheme2]

So.. I pull P61(H_RST) down and it sets reset line low. However when I pull it up after that I get infinite switches between low and high levels on it.

Here is also my handmade atmega16L board schematic which faces the same problem:

[image: atmega16L]

Comment: What is driving this?

Comment: 2N7000 is not a good choice. Use a BSS138.

Comment: The Vgs(th) for the 2N7000 is too high to work reliably in 3.3V circuits.

Comment: If you approach this as an analog issue, it will make sense.  Rather than LA, use scope and Vgs(th) must be <=1V

Comment: @mkeith sorry, my fault. I actually use bss. It is just an image from web. Fixed it.

Comment: @Trevor arm chip is driving in Push-Pull mode.

Comment: Arm chip... Would you like to be a bit more specific, and can you show the output waveform that is driving this.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, why Vgs(th) <= 1V for this application ?

Comment: Rds(on) is rated well above Vgs(th) is the short answer ,usually 3x Vgs(th) , (3.3 -Vf)/3=1.0, Why Vf? look carefully at Vol to AVR...

Comment: I suspect this is a logical problem rather than a level shifter design problem. For example, there's some device you're expecting to drive the RESET line high. When you pull down the RESET line, does that hold this device in the reset state?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, it holds.

Comment: Then how do you expect that device to ever drive the RESET line high?

Comment: You should include your full schematic if possible. At least the part that shows what the RESET line is connected to on both sides of the level translator. Edit your question and click Ctrl-M to use the built in schematic editor or upload an image of the schematic if you already have one.

Comment: "three different boards... arduino/avr" - are all 3 boards Ardunios (or equivalent to an Arduino)?

Comment: @BruceAbbott three different boards refers to arduino uno, mega and one handmade atmega16L board. It worths to notice that I also tried two converters: hand made based on transistors and one based on txb.

Comment: @ThePhoton schematic will be rather useless because it is only a simple shield for cc3200-launchpad which has logic converter on it and nothing more. There is just gpio connected from 3.3v side and reset line with pullup on arduino/avr side line.

Comment: "three different boards refers to arduino uno, mega and one handmade atmega16L board." - and the atmega16L board, is it running the same firmware?

Comment: A schematic for the whole system, not just for the logic converter. The more you share, the more we can give answers that will actually help you.

Comment: @ThePhoton take a look at the update please.

Comment: @BruceAbbott no, atmega16L is just an empty mcu and arduinos have their bootloader. I am trying to program them actually.

Comment: @BruceAbbott moreover if I hold reset button pressed on either of  AVR boards they got programmed. All other lines like SPI are connected via the same logic shifter scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the reset circuit you will see it is a simple analog RC delay.

[image]

As such, it is really an analog signal. It will therefore hang around in the grey logic area for a while as it transitions. Even without the cap, since the line is only pulled high through resistors, the capacitance of the MOSFET itself will significantly decrease the rise time.

You need to add a Schmidt trigger buffer in there to give you some hysteresis on the signal before you throw it at that level shifter. Otherwise the level shifter will flip on and off with any noise in your general neighborhood.

Comment: Hm.. Sounds very reasonable. Will check it asap. However I do not have rc circuit on my handmade avr board. I've found a schematic and attached it.

Comment: @LongSmith reread my answer, your MOSFET is a nice cap all on it's own.

Comment: Something telling me that you are right. I am to check it and then give you know about the results. Thanks!

Comment: @LongSmith rule of thumb.."If your circuit works for all signals but one... ask yourself, What is different about the signal itself?" Your answer will be there 99% of the time.

Comment: I asked it many times already ;) However the year after taking my last electronics course has wiped out anything connected to mosfet capacitance from my mind. Sure I recall it much better now.

Comment: It took me a while to check but it seems working now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you approach this as an analog issue, it will make sense. Rather than LA, use scope and Vgs(th) must be <=1V, ignoring tolerance (3.3 -Vf)/3= 1V.

Rds(on) is always rated well above Vgs(th) is the short answer, since Rds is very high at threshold.

- usually Vgs = 3x Vgs(th) is adequate for low R , here maybe 2x into 10k.

  Why Vf? look carefully at Vol path to AVR... from right to left.

Comment: I am gonna take a look tomorrow since I have no access to scope right now.

Comment: You can disconnect 5V port, ground it and measure 3V port voltage and it should be <=0.8V, the lower it is , the more noise margin. Above this it is prone to ground noise , Common mode stray noise , etc.